# Using pre-defined overlays in Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

well i was able to find loads of information on how to create my own custom overlays onto the map, but none on how can i use the ones that google already has put on.
I basically want to use all the overlays of one type (say the Hotel overlay icons) and get their geoPoints and then use them in any way i want...right now i have to manually get the geoPoint of every such hotel overlay and then use them, which is pretty painful considering google has already marked them out...but i have no idea how can i use them..
Any idea how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not available to Android SDK developers -- they are part of the proprietary Google Maps application. The only pre-built overlay available to SDK developers is `MyLocationOverlay`.

Comment: so even though they are marked, a developer can utilize them and instead have to create custom overlays on top of them?

Comment: @Urban: A developer cannot "utilize them". Overlays that you see in the Google Maps application are not available to Android SDK developers. If you want an overlay for hotels for your `MapView`, you will need to write the code for the overlay yourself, find the hotels yourself, etc.

Comment: ok..thx...but i guess google would done everyone a favor by allowing these overlays to be used...